# Как создать вспомогательную функцию

Tags: javascript

Есть три похожих кода:

```js
function startEdit(id, name) {
  setNotes(
    notes.map((note) => {
      if (note.id === id) {
        const fields = note.fields.map((field) => {
          if (field.name === name) {
            return { ...field,
              isEdit: true
            }
          } else return field
        })
        return {
          id,
          fields
        }
      } else {
        return note
      }
    })
  )
}

function endEdit(id, name) {
  setNotes(
    notes.map((note) => {
      if (note.id === id) {
        const fields = note.fields.map((field) => {
          if (field.name === name) {
            return { ...field,
              isEdit: false
            }
          } else return field
        })
        return {
          id,
          fields
        }
      } else {
        return note
      }
    })
  )
}

function changeCell(id, name, e) {
  setNotes(
    notes.map((note) => {
      if (note.id === id) {
        const fields = note.fields.map((field) => {
          if (field.name === name) {
            return { ...field,
              value: e.target.value
            }
          } else return field
        })
        return {
          id,
          fields
        }
      } else {
        return note
      }
    })
  )
}
```

Как создать вспомогательную функцию и сократить код?

Answer (score 0):

```
setNotes(notes => notes.map(wrapperMap({isEdit: true })));
setNotes(notes => notes.map(wrapperMap({isEdit: false })));
setNotes(notes => notes.map(wrapperMap({value: e.target.value })));

function wrapperMap(obj) {
  return (note) => {
    if (note.id === id) {
      const fields = note.fields.map((field) =>
        field.name === name ? { ...field, ...obj } : field
      );
      return { id, fields };
    }
    return note;
  };
}
```